# Way to get the output of an abstract function

Tags: php, abstract-class, base-class

I have an abstract class with an abstract method 'run'. Child classes extending this implements run and returns a bool as output.
Is there a way that I can get the status of run (true/false) method in the abstract class.

I want this as I am trying to add few statistics as how many classes failed/passed to execute the run method. I already have many classes extending this and don't want to add anything into those and get these statistics for free.

```
abstract class parent {
  // I need the status of the run method in here
  public abstract function run(); 
}

class child extends parent {
  public function run() {
   if (implementation) {
     return true;
     } else {
     return false;
     }
   }
}
```

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Define a non-abstract method in the parent that calls the abstract method and gets the result.

```
abstract class parent {
    private $run_result;

    public function run() {
        $this->run_result = $this->run_internal();
    }
    abstract protected function run_internal();
}

class child extends parent {
    protected function run_internal() {
        if (implementation) {
            return true;
        } else {
        return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But then I need to call run(). class child above calls run_internal which doesn't invoke run().

Comment: The child class doesn't call `run_internal()`, it *implements* it. The parent class calls it when the application calls `run()`.